# How can I choose the API 22 with "cordova build android"? (Cordova doesn't listen to manifestandroid.xml)

Tags: android, cordova

When I compile ionic 3 app with cordova using:

"cordova build android"

And i get:

"BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 40.994 secs
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
  >   [Android SDK Platform 25].
  >   Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  >   Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
  >   [**Android SDK Platform 25**].
  >   Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  >   Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M"

The question is how can I choose the TARGET API?.
I want target API 22, not the 25 API. If I add the following 
`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />` 
to the platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml I get the same error.

The question is: **How can I choose the API 22 with "cordova build android"?**.

I read a lot here about that and had no luck.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try playing with these settings in config.xml:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion"    value="22" />
<preference name="android-maxSdkVersion"    value="22" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="22" />
```

Possibly minSdkVersion can be lower, etc.

Comment: I test a lot. I see that there are two androidmanifest.xml and two config.xml.
In all i could put the targetSDKversion.
In androidmanifest.xml i see it is overwritten after compiling.
And i see two config.xml:
1) one in the root
2) and another in root/www/appname/config.xml

I test in both, i think if i don't touch the config.xml (1) and i touch config.xml (2) (add your code in config.xml (2)) i think the apk has the target api i want. 

Is that config.xml the right file?

Comment: There should only be one config.xml in the root of your project. The www folder beneath the root of your project should only have the code you want to run inside your Cordova app. (HTML, CSS, JavaScript, etc.)